# Proper use of possessives

Tags: nouns, possessives

If I wanted to talk about treasure owned by **multiple** explorers, how would I write it?

> The explorers' treasure.

OR

> The explorer's treasure.

Is the plural form of *explorer* considered irregular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of *explorer* (as with any regular noun; *explorer* is not irregular), [plural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural) adds *-s* (i.e. *explorers*),  [possessive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive_suffix) adds *-'s* (*explorer's*), but both plural and possessive together add *-s'* (*explorers'*).  Therefore, your first example is correct:

> The explorers' treasure

Comment: Thanks. How would it be pronounced phonetically?

Comment: All three options in my answer would be pronounced the same.